# How did Hamilton come up with his idea of summing up the kinetic energy and potential energy?

Tags: energy, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, history

When we browse through any classical physics textbook, the Lagrangian comes first where the potential energy is subtracted from Kinetic energy. Was [Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) playing around with energy functions and he got the idea of summing up both the energies?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Sir William Rowan Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Rowan_Hamilton) briefly discusses the history.

Comment: Well, I could slightly rephrase my questions as "What was lagging in the Lagrangian formulation that led Hamilton to invent his own method? I have seen applications of Hamiltonian mechanics in quantum mechanics but he invented it way before the quantum mechanics evolved.

Comment: I strongly believe you should delete your question and ask it instead in [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) where it really belongs.